# Best OS for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3

I am getting a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with 1 GB RAM and quad core processor. I am looking for a light weight operating system to install on it. I will be using it mostly for web browsing. I was thinking of Ubuntu, but the standard Ubuntu already eats up most of the RAM. Is there a light version of Ubuntu without all the unnecessary background processes? Or perhaps another light linux distribution that is still not too primitive? I wonder how good raspbian is? Any thoughts?

Comment: We don't know what criteria you would use to choose between the options.   You need to do your own research.

Comment: The criteria is minimum ram usage wiithout being command-line to provide good web browsing experience.

Comment: Light weight Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi 3? I think you are looking for Ubuntu MATE for Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Mate is just nicer and more friendly but more resource hungry than Raspbian. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y_yLW9Y7KU

Answer (score 2):

I'm very happy with Raspbian on the Pi 3. Tho I'd be much happier with a 64-bit version, but the 32-bit version is already fast enough.

[image: Browser]

[image: usage]

I can't say that the GUI is eating all resources. You could try the Windows OS to get some punishment.

Answer (score 0):

Different OS's are best at different things. But if you are wanting to do web browsing, the Raspberry Pi isn't a very good device for that. The GUI bogs the Pi down, making browsing painful. Raspberry Pi's are best used for command-line accessible processing power.

Comment: I disagree they're ok ish as long as you don't expect too much, he said he's getting a pi 3 B not a 2 A or something similar, it's more powerfull than the pc i had when i started by a long shot and that did web browsing just fine

Comment: I agree with @RonanThibaudau the pi 3 and 2 are just fine for web browsing. In fact i am writing this comment from my pi.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have any reason to go with a particular distro i'd stick with raspbian that is tailor made for the raspberry